# C - multiple definition of function during building large project

Tags: c

I'm trying to build large project and in it I have the following header file

error.h

```
#ifndef __ERROR_H__
#define __ERROR_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void error_validate_pointer(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error with allocating memory");
        exit(1);
    }
}

#endif /* __ERROR_H__ */
```

I use this often function in every .c file I have (I include "error.h" in every file) but I thought this #ifndef would protect me from multiple definition error. Yet, during building, I get the following errors:

```
../dictionary/libdictionary.a(state_list.c.o): In function `error_validate_pointer':
/home/pgolinski/Dokumenty/Programowanie/spellcheck-pg359186/src/dictionary/error.h:8: multiple definition of `error_validate_pointer'
../dictionary/libdictionary.a(hint.c.o):/home/pgolinski/Dokumenty/Programowanie/spellcheck-pg359186/src/dictionary/error.h:8: first defined here
../dictionary/libdictionary.a(state_set.c.o): In function `error_validate_pointer':
/home/pgolinski/Dokumenty/Programowanie/spellcheck-pg359186/src/dictionary/error.h:8: multiple definition of `error_validate_pointer'
../dictionary/libdictionary.a(hint.c.o):/home/pgolinski/Dokumenty/Programowanie/spellcheck-pg359186/src/dictionary/error.h:8: first defined here
```

What could be the reason I keep getting these errors? How to avoid it?

Comment: Declare the function `static` in each file. This is a linker error. The preprocessor mechanism that you're trying to solve it with is not going to work. The compiler handles each source file completely independently of all others. In other words, it "forgets" all previous definitions every time it starts working on a source file. The `ifndef/define` is used in order to prevent "repeating definitions" while working **on a given source file**, but not beyond it. At the end of compilation, multiple **instances** (global functions or variables) are considered linkage errors.

Comment: Generally .h files don't contain actual code. Usually they only contain declarations and/or preprocessor `#defines` and macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because you `#include` a definition several times, so that you actually end up having multiple definitions - one for every file you include it in.

Change your code to

```
#ifndef __ERROR_H__
#define __ERROR_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void error_validate_pointer(void *ptr);

#endif /* __ERROR_H__ */
```

... for the header, so it only contains a declaration of the function.

Then create a new file (e.g. `error.c`) with the definition

```
#include "error.h"

void error_validate_pointer(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error with allocating memory");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to separating the function into it's own C file, if you declare the function as static, you can define it in the header file.  If you place inline is as well gcc won't compile about the unused static function.  By declaring it a static function it's name won't be visible outside the object file so you won't get a conflict.  This will result in the function being defined multiple times though so it would make your code larger, depending on how often you use it.

Your code in the end would be:

```
#ifndef __ERROR_H__
#define __ERROR_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline void error_validate_pointer(void *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error with allocating memory");
        exit(1);
    }
}

#endif /* __ERROR_H__ */
```